# $\int_{\frac{1}{3}\pi}^{\frac{2}{3}\pi} {\sin(x)\;dx}$ using Riemann sums?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

How to find the integral $$\int_{\frac{1}{3}\pi}^{\frac{2}{3}\pi} {\sin(x)\;dx}=1$$ using Riemann sums?

Comment: Do you know what the upper and lower sums are?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53752.html  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128186/riemann-sum-of-sinx

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Unfortunately not $: '($

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will use the [Lagrange trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\frac12\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}-1\right)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(kx)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)\sin\left(\frac n2x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}
$$
The Riemann Sum is
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac\pi3+\frac\pi3\frac kn\right)\frac\pi{3n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi3\frac kn\right)+\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\sin\left(\frac\pi3\frac kn\right)\right)\frac\pi{3n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\frac\pi{6n}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\frac\pi{3n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12\frac\pi{3n}\right)}-1\right)+\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\frac\pi{3n}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\frac\pi{3n}\right)\sin\left(\frac n2\frac\pi{3n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12\frac\pi{3n}\right)}\\
&=\sin^2\left(\frac\pi3\right)+2\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\sin^2\left(\frac\pi6\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac34+2\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac14\\[15pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do you have some further reading for those identities?

Comment: Are you asking about [Lagrange's Trigonometric Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities)?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\sin(a) \sin(h/2) = \dfrac{\cos(a - h/2) - \cos(a + h/2)}{2}$ can be used to get a nice formula for $\sin(a) + \sin(a+h) + \ldots \sin(a + nh)$.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \sin\left(\frac{\pi(ni+1)}{3} \right)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{n\pi}{3} \right)=1??$$

Comment: $$\int_{\frac{1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{2}{3}\pi}\sin{x}\;\;dx= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \sin\left(\frac{\pi(ni+1)}{3} \right)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{n\pi}{3} \right)=1$$ Correct?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: the intervals in the partition should be getting smaller as $n\to\infty$. Your intervals seem to be getting bigger.