# Finding the integral of $\sin(x)\,dx$ using Riemann sums?

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know how to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\sin(x)\;dx}=1$$

using Riemann sums.

If someone could please show me step by step and explain I would be very grateful!
Edit: I did see the other question but I don't think I need to use trig identities on this. I'm still confused about how to go further than the setup.

Comment: Start off my draw the graph with 'upper' and 'lower' triangles.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128186/riemann-sum-of-sinx .

Answer (score 2):

$a= 0$, $b = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ gives that

$$ \Delta x = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{\pi}{2n}. $$

Therefore $x_k = a+k\dfrac{b-a}{n}=0+k\dfrac{\pi}{2n}= \dfrac{k\pi}{2n}$

Thus $\displaystyle f(x_k)=\sin(x_k)= \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\Delta x &= \frac{\pi}{2n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\bigg) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2n} \frac{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big)\sin\big((n+1)\frac{\pi}{4n}\big)}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{4n}\big)}
\end{align*}

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)\, dx= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{2n} \frac{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big)\sin\big((n+1)\frac{\pi}{4n}\big)}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{4n}\big)} = 2 \sin^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg) = 1. $$

Comment: this is a pain to read. Could greatly benefit from some formatting.

Comment: This reads like a cryptic telegram.

Comment: The methodology is sound.  Well done.  +1 ... Might want to edit and tidy it up a bit to appease others.

Comment: Where did the n go before you took the limit?

Comment: They paired up and got simplifed by the limiting process.

Comment: Shouldn't your index start at $k=1$? A riemann sum is summing up $n$ terms if you're dividing your intervals in $n$ equally spaced subintervals. Not that it matters in your specific example.

Comment: Just fixed it $k = 1 \to n$.